# What would be the JAR used to connect to a Weblogic JMS server from Websphere server

Tags: jms, websphere, weblogic

I am trying to connect to JMS queue which is present in a Weblogic server. My client application is deployed in Websphere application server WAS. What are the jars which I have to use in-order to create a JMS provider to connect to Weblogic JMS? In need of your helps please...

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of WLS:

- `<WebLogic_Directory>\server\lib\wlclient.jar`
- `<WebLogic_Directory>\server\lib\wljmsclient.jar`

Newer versions of WebLogic Server

- `<WebLogic_Directory>\server\lib\wlthint3client.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The relevant Oracle documentation for "the newest" (at the moment of writing) WebLogic Server 12c version:

[Oracle® Fusion Middleware Developing Standalone Clients for Oracle WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SACLT/title.htm)

As you can see for [JMS clients](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SACLT/basics.htm#SACLT122) there is several options like:

- WebLogic Thin T3 client
- JMS thin client

and others depending on your use case.

In all cases you'll find the libraries from `WL_HOME\server\lib` directory of your WebLogic Server installation.